# override save and load of an attribute in magento

Tags: magento, attributes

How can I override the way magento saves and load a specific attribute?
I want to create an attribute that implements a many-to-many relation to products
so I have a custom table with entity_id and attr_id.
I'm using a multiselect attribute but magento saves the values as csv in a text field.
I want to override this functionality and save and load from the m2m table.

When defining a backend model for an attribute I only have control over beforeSave and afterSave but not on save itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to create a custom module with your own Model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.  That way you can override the `save()` function (always making sure that you call `parent::save()` in there too!) to perform your multi-table logic.

Once you've created that model, can you create a product attribute that uses the Model as a `frontend_model` and/or `backend_model`. You can create the attribute in the `config.xml` of your module or in the [mysql setup](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-adding-attribute-from-mysql-setup-file/).

This is not trivial, and be careful with overriding the `save()` method, that's getting in deep.  Good idea to setup some unit tests to make sure you're not inadvertently breaking things...

Comment: I already built a custom module with a custom attribute. I defined a backend and source models for this attribute. I couldn't find a save method in Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract, Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract or Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract. What attribute model calls or extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()?

Comment: you can't override Mage_Core_Model_Abstract via a Module.  The only classes Magento allows you to override are classes you can instantiate, and you can't instantiate an abstract class.  This is a limitation of userspace PHP.

Comment: @Alan, true, I worded my answer poorly.  I meant that by creating your own module, you can define `save()` within your `Namespace_Module_Model_Model` that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` thereby overriding the abstract `save()`.  Doesn't that achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Pablo, if you create a Model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and have your backend and source objects call that Model for their data, that could work?

Also, have a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice` for an interesting example.  It extends `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract` which provides the opportunity to override `save()`

Comment: Ah, I misread what you said.  I thought you were recommending overriding the abstract class's save. Re-reading it, its clear you're recommending that pablo override the save method of whatever model contains the attribute.